# Is it possible to hit your own men with normal weapons?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I know you can damage your own men with rockets and grenades, but when firing your regular weapon is it possible to cause friendly fire?

I've had a few situations where two troops were close together and when the soldier lined up to shoot the bullets (or energy) passed very close (or maybe something through) another unit to the target.

I know in the original X-COM friendly fire was definitely possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no friendly fire with "normal" weapons assuming the unit is friendly (e.g. not mind controlled or panicking).  You *can* blow up a friendly's cover, though.

Comment: I've had incidents where a soldier missed and his plasma hit a friendly, and it didn't do any damage to them even then.

Comment: @SaintWacko I have had quite a few of those.  Though I will say I'm not sure how much I trust animations; sometimes it looks like my bolt hits an enemy (or vice versa), but I get a miss.  I suspect the bolt there is hitting the cover, but the nature of the particular cover just makes it look like it's hitting the target(e.g. cover behind a wall that's mostly absent but still giving you a half-shield).

Comment: It is definitely possible with aliens though.  I've seen cases where an alien tried to shoot me but ended up damaging an ally of his.  Though I haven't seen cases where I'm trying to shoot an alien and then accidentally shoot one of his allies instead, but those chances are pretty rare in the first place since they rarely line up.

Comment: @yx. - I've seen that once, where one of my shots missed and hit another alien.

Comment: @saintwacko interesting, so aliens can have friendly fire and accidental fire but your units can't?

Comment: My best/worst FF moment is when 2 Mutons hiding behind the far left end of a bank of 2 alien terminals, 2 squad mates hiding by the right terminal and my Heavy on the other end. Heavy let loose a rocket and hit the right terminal display, killing 2 friendlies, exposing himself to the Mutons!